# How can I specify the input source for the AudioRecorder object?

Tags: android, android-ndk, opensl

I'm porting an audio capture loop from Java (using `AudioRecord` class) to a native library using OpenSL.

The reason for this is that after profiling, the capture loop is consuming in our test phones around 2% less CPU in OpenSL. That is a significative gain!

The constructor for the Java AudioRecord class receives a `source` parameter that can be configured to several values (`MIC, CAMCORDER, VOICE_DOWNLINK`, etc.)

So far, I haven't been able to find the equivalence (if there exists) for the source parameter in OpenSL.

Does anybody know if  there's a way to specify this Source parameter for the AudioRecorder object?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the functions and constants defined in `SLES/OpenSLES_Android.h` and `SLES/OpenSLES_AndroidConfiguration.h`.  When you get your recording object from OpenSLES, use `GetInterface()` to get the interface pointer for `SL_IID_ANDROIDCONFIGURATION`.  From there you can call `SetConfiguration()` using key `SL_ANDROID_KEY_RECORDING_PRESET` on the returned `SLAndroidConfigurationItf` pointer.

Comment: Thank you very much @kelnos, this is exactly what I was looking for - there's very little documentation available on the subject!

Comment: Yeah, for me it was a bit of trial and error and poking around at headers, as well as finding some code out in the wild that did something similar.  The documentation is terrible!